# Iterator(of a vector or string) minus n (iter - n) for c++

Tags: c++, iterator

Some detail description for my question:

1. Create an iterator of vector or string in c++ 11.
2. Do iterator arithmetic, iterator minus n

Question: Will c++ 11 keep the iterator minus n bigger than begin()? (if n is big enough, will the compiler ensure that the iter - n do not exceed the legal range of iterator?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator#Requirements), `iter - n` is effectively the same as:

```cpp
vector<T>::iterator temp = iter;
while(n--) --temp;
return temp;
```

Assuming `iter` was a iterator from a `vector` named `container`. If `n` is larger than `distance(container.begin(), iter)`, then at some point from the last `while` loop, `--temp` would be equivalent of:

```cpp
--container.begin();
```

And according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator#Notes), that line would be undefined behavior.

Since an iterator cannot know any information of the originated container, it does not have a way to detect if it is currently `container.begin()`, thus it cannot ensure it to be remained in the legal range without manually checking against the range.

Comment: 'Since an iterator cannot know any information of the originated container', well it could but the standard does not require iterators to have that capability. You could certainly imagine debug builds that would do all sorts of checking in iterators (just like the debug asset referenced below).

Answer (score 1):

It will not, it will simply perform the arithmetic operations and print the values in negative number.

Performed the code using VSCode.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    vector<int> :: iterator it;

    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
        cout<<*it-6<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

and the results were :

```
 -5
 -4
 -3
 -2
 -1
  0
```

Comment: Sorry, this example only shows that 6 can be subtracted from the numbers 1 to 6. Did you mean to demonstrate the undefined behavior of `*(it-6)` (note the parentheses)?

Answer (score 0):

No, iterator arithmetic will not do any bounds checking on the result.  You can easily end up with an invalid iterator.

A random access iterator such as given by `std::vector` will allow you to do subtraction, so you can impose your own bounds checking.

```
it2 = it - min(n, it - container.begin());
```